# How do I make Sublime stop changing Tab Width back to 4 after I change it?

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation

I like having my tab width set to 2, but when I close a file and/or reopen sublime it resets to 4.

Also I'm a total noob.

Answer (score 1):

Disable indentation detection - sublimetext.com/docs/2/indentation.html